# Android TextView html added url not working

Tags: android, html, url, textview

I'm developing an app in Java with targetSdkVersion set to 30. I have an activity where I need to display to a user a clickable URL in form of **click me** with the long URL hidden within supporting HTML.

I'm struggling for some time. Currently my code works as below

```
            if (station.getSponsorUrl().length() > 32) {
                stationSponsorUrl.setClickable(true);
                stationSponsorUrl.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
                stationSponsorUrl.setText(Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"" + station.getSponsorUrl() +"\">" + getString(R.string.www_link) + "</a>\n", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
            }
            else {
                stationSponsorUrl.setText(station.getSponsorUrl());
            }
```

When I remove a call to `setMovementMethod` the URL renders correctly (font color) but it is not clickable at all. When I leave `setMovementMethod` active it is not even displayed as a URL. I see the text defined by `R.string.www_link` in the unchanged format. Of course it is also not working.

`else` case works correctly and when I set the TV content with plain HTML link it works out of the box. The tv is defined in XML layout as below

```
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textViewSponsorUrl"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                        android:autoLink="all"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/alegreya_sans_sc_medium"
                        android:linksClickable="true"
                        android:text="TextView"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running into trouble using `android:autoLink="all"` in your layout. I suggest that you delete that autolink line and adjust your code as follows:

```
stationSponsorUrl.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
String anchorText;
if (station.getSponsorUrl().length() > 32) {
    anchorText = getString(R.string.www_link)
} else {
    anchorText = station.getSponsorUrl()
}
stationSponsorUrl.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
stationSponsorUrl.setText(
    HtmlCompat.fromHtml(
        "<a href=\"" + station.getSponsorUrl() + "\">" + anchorText + "</a>\n", HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY
    )
);
```

You could also turn autolink off for long URLs using [setAutoLinkMask()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setAutoLinkMask(int)):

```
stationSponsorUrl.setAutoLinkMask(0)
```

Comment: Thank You It works as it should. I only had to add `           stationSponsorUrl.setAutoLinkMask(0);` one line before Your code snippet and shortened URLs started to work OK.